# How to persist Bluemix files between app restarts

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, paperclip, ibm-cloud

I am using a rails 4 application on Bluemix, attaching files using paperclip gem. As we all know, Paperclip is saving a reference to that file in the actual db, saving the physical file into a `/public` location.

I am submitting a file to this db which is getting saved here

`/home/vcap/app/public/files/submissions/files/140/original/Successful_Submission.pdf`

and then the file retrieval is working perfectly fine. Once I restart my app, I get:

```
Errno::ENOENT (No such file or directory @ rb_file_s_lstat - /home/vcap/app/public/files/submissions/files/140/original/Successful_Submission.pdf):
```

And this is because Bluemix is not persisting this information. How can I get hold of those files between app restarts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bluemix is built on top of Cloud Foundry and it has an ephemeral filesystem, i.e., once your application stops the platform will claim back that filesystem and creates a brand new one once you restart your application.

Writing to the local filesystem is not recommended for cloud applications and you may need to redesign your application to work with Bluemix. One solution is to save your files in your database and not only the reference.

You can find more details on this [link](https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/deploy-apps/prepare-to-deploy.html).

Comment: Thanks for your comment @alex. Unfortunately, this is how my gem works and there is no tweak I can put in place to save the file in the actual database, instead of saving it into the filesystem. I will have some backups, by sending the file to a box folder in the same time, but is there no chance to cache the information from the file system in Bluemix?

Comment: there is no caching option in Bluemix filesystem. Everything created at runtime in the filesystem will be lost when you restart your application.

Comment: @VladBalanescu -  One hacky technique that I've used for some projects is to use SSHFS (fusemount) support within the Bluemix CF app to map to a ssh enabled IBM Container (Docker) instance which uses a persisted volume.  Depending on the size of the files, it can sometimes work ok.  You can get a sense for the approach [here](https://github.com/joshisa/drupalstart/blob/master/bluezone/configtweaks/.profile.d/fusemount.sh) and [here](https://github.com/joshisa/drupalstart/blob/master/README.md#sshfs-persisted-storage-optional)

Answer (score 0):

Each application instance on Bluemix (which is based on Cloud Foundry) has ephemeral storage. This storage is only available for the lifetime of that particular instance. When you redeploy your app then you'll get a new app instance and any data on the previous app instance will be inaccessible.

There's a good explanation of why it's best to [avoid writing to the local file system](https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/deploy-apps/prepare-to-deploy.html#filesystem) when designing an application for Bluemix / Cloud Foundry.

You may want to take a look at a gem like [CarrierWave to store the files on Amazon S3](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave#using-amazon-s3) or another persistent store. There's also [Paperclip](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip) which offers similar functionality.